# Reading and writing multiple files in a consistent order

Tags: python

I'm trying to read multiple files and then save them after I have processed each one. Right now I'm able to do so but the order is not correct. As I'm accessing a text file, each third line corresponds to a frame in order (Frame 1=line3, Frame2=line6), so I need my code to read the images in order.

```
path = '/Users/Desktop/FFMPEG/results25'
for i, image in enumerate(glob.glob("/Users/Desktop/FFMPEG/test25/*.png"), 1):
    img = cv2.imread(image)
    data_number =i   #frame number and max is 918
    n = data_number*3

    with open('FS_25FULL.txt') as f:
        lines = f.readlines() #Returns a list where each line is a list item
        data = lines[n].split(")") #returns a list
        list_data = [string.replace('(', '').replace(' ', '').split(",") for string in data]
        list_data.pop(-1)


    cv2.line(img, P_1, P_2, color=(0,255,255), thickness=2) 
    cv2.line(img, P_1, P_3, color=(0,255,255), thickness=2) 


    def global_vector_cal(LIST_DATA):
        counter_vector = 0
        #rest of my code


   cv2.imwrite(os.path.join(path, 'img_{}.png'.format(i)), img)
```

The image names I have are `results25_00001.png`, `results25_00002` and so on. The saved files are saved as `img_1.png`, `img_2.png` and so on, but they are not in the order of the `results25` images that are in incremental order. How can I change that?

Comment: Do you mean that you want to save the files as `img_00001.png` and so on?

Comment: No I mean when its accessing my images, its not doing so in order bur rather randomly. The images are from a video sequence so when its being saved the order is messed up because the accessing part is random

Comment: What is "it" that is accessing your images? Do you mean that your program does not access the `results25*` images in the order you want or that something else does not access the `img_*` files your program creates in the order you want
?

Comment: You would need to sort the results from `glob.glob()` if you wanted them to be in any particular order.

Comment: Or do you mean that you want to reuse the same number that is in the `results25*` filename for the `img_*` result file?

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear, yes I mean my program is not accessing images in the order I want. The images are saved in incrementing numbers but they do not correspond to the initial image sequence

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expanding on the comment by @jasonharper: instead of using

```
glob.glob("/Users/Desktop/FFMPEG/test25/*.png")
```

you could try to use:

```
sorted(glob.glob("/Users/Desktop/FFMPEG/test25/*.png"))
```

It is a bit hard to provide an answer without a fully reproducible example, and output (desired and obtained).

Comment: Thank you for your help, it worked! I'll try to be more clear in the future

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers - on this site you should mark the question as solved and vote it - that is the way to say thank you (but read the link has all the details and recommendations)